# Continuous Integration of Repositories from GitHub using Python

Tags: python-3.x, github, gitpython

I want to download multiple repositories from GitHub using Python libraries. I found gitpython, but I don't know how to write a program which continuously forks repositories. Any suggestions how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fork ("[fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)") in order to clone or pull from a repo you want to monitor.

You need either a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)** (if you have access to the repo) in order to be alerted of any new commit.
Or you need a CI tool (for instance, [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) to regularely to a pull, and trigger a job if any new commit has changed.

Comment: I have to download around 100 projects related to Python. And I have to then check the commits and create patch files.

Comment: @Mia OK, but you still don't have to "fork" those project, do you?

Comment: Like I have an algorithm in mind if I will be able to fork those repositories, I can extract the commits url.

Comment: By fork, do you mean clone?

Comment: Ok, I will check tomorrow, but my point was: a fork is not a clone.